# Output attribute value with XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

Example:

```
 <div class='known' name='unknown'>
```

How can I return `name` attribute value ('unknown') based on known `class` attribure value, with XPath 1.0?

While looking for an answer I found that XPath 2.0 has instrument for this:

```
 //div[@class='known']/@name/string()
```

But can't find XPath 1.0 analogy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
string(//div[@class='known']/@name)
```

This produces the string value of the `name` attribute *of the first* in document order `div` element such that the string value of its `class` attribute is `"unknown"`.

If `//div[@class='known']` selects more than one `div` element and you want the value of the `name` attribute for the k-th selected `div`, use:

```
string((//div[@class='known'])[$k]/@name)
```

where `$k` has to be substituted with the wanted integer, or otherwise the variable `$k` must be in the evaluation context for the XPath expression.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to output all elements? I tried with `string((//div[@class='known'])[*]/@name)` but it doesn't work

Comment: @zetah: Not with a single XPath 1.0 expression. However, it is possible to select with a single XPath 1.0 expression all the elements or all their `name` attributes. Then the output can be done in a loop in the host programming language.